# ADB shell screenrecord recorded different size from its recorded frame

Tags: android, adb

I use the below command to record a video from my device

```
adb shell screenrecord /sdcard/video.mp4
```

However the size came up oddly where instead of filling up the entire device screen available, it shrink, and leaving the right and bottom black color as per picture below. In short the video is smaller than the frame it shows it recorded.

[image]

What causes this, and how could I solve it? (It used to be good in the past, where the screen recoded fit into the frame)

Comment: Did you ever figured this out?